# Autorun transfer from USB

Tags: automation

I am looking to automatically execute a series of tasks when a USB is plugged into a new Android tablet (running 11). Does anyone know if this is possible?

Needs:

1. Plug USB into new Android tablet
2. Power up in tablet
3. Transfer a folder from the root drive on the USB to the root drive of the Android device
4. Run an APK from within the new folder on the root drive of the Android device

Comment: You may want to switch to adb instead of MTP. On the phone enable Android Developer Options and Android Debug bridge (ADB). adb requires installation of "Adb minimal" or "Android SDK" on PC side but it works way more reliable than standard MTP USB file transfer and is way better for scripting especially when te PC is running Windows.

Comment: Running an Android APK without installing is not possible. Via adb you can install an APK using `adb install <apkfile>` on the PC or on the phone `pm install <apkfile>` (executed in an adb shell).

Comment: Rubber ducky? You cannot be using a USB drive for that though. However, you will not be able to send apk through this (i think) So you can put it on bit.ly or somewhere and get it downloaded. Also TRY THESE ONLY ON YOUR OWN DEVICES. https://anirbanroy.co.in/how-to-make-usb-rubber-ducky-in-2022-for-android/